# TikZ external Library and pgfplots reading data from external txt file

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I'm using the external library of TikZ for speeding up the compilation of my LaTeX document.  In another thread, Christian Feuersänger reported that from December 2012, the external library uses MD5 checksums to find out whether a source file changed or not and whether the corresponding figure must be re-built in order to be up-to-date. This works fine for my figures that have been made using plain TikZ.

However, I also use pgfplots to plot the run of variables whose data is stored in an external txt file. This is a MWE of what I do and how I do it:

```
%%% this is the main.tex file %%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\tikzexternalize
\tikzsetexternalprefix{./PDF/}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \tikzsetfigurename{fluk-p}
  \tikzpicturedependsonfile{data.txt}
  \input{fluk-p.tex}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

%%% This is the fluk-p.tex file %%%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xlabel={Zeit\,[s]}]      ]
\addplot [color=red] table [x index=0,y index=1] {data.txt};
\addplot [color=blue] table [x index=0,y index=2] {data.txt};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%%% This is the data.txt file %%%
0  1  2
1  2  1
2  1  2
```

If I change something in the fluk-p.tex file -- say the xlabel -- TikZ finds out correctly and re-builds the figure. But if I change something in the corresponding data.txt file TikZ does not notice this. I thought I could fix this issue with the \tikzpicturedependsonfile{data.txt} command but I was wrong obviously.

Can anybody help how I can make TikZ to notice changes not only in the fluk-p.tex but also in the data.txt?

Thanks in advance!
Sven

Comment: Hi Sven, welcome to the site! Could you confirm if Jake's link resolves the issue? If it doesn't, could you describe how? Welcome!

Comment: Thanks for your comment and thanks to Jake for linking to a prior question that also addresses this issue. For some reason I must have overlooked it.
I guess that Jake's link resolves my issue but I'm having some problems with the `list and make` option and the `make` command right now. I downloaded GNU's `make` from here [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) but if I run `make` with the `main.makefile`, `make` reports **process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cat main.figlist, ...) failed.**

Comment: There seems to bee something wrong with the `make.exe` I was using. I now use the `make.exe` that comes along with the MinGW distribution. Everything works perfectly now.